# T-SQL: Sort by column with not every row contains data

Tags: sorting, t-sql

I have sample data as follows:

```
    taskname  |skillname |user  |Partition
    --------------------------------------
    taskAAAA  |skill1111 |user3 |1   
              |skill2222 |      |1  
    taskBBBB  |skill1111 |user2 |2  
    taskCCCC  |skill3333 |user1 |3 
    taskDDDD  |skill1111 |user4 |4   
              |skill2222 |      |4
```

If there are two skills belongs to a task, taskname and user will not repeat itself in taskname column and user column.

I manage to put partition to the same taskname. But I need to sort by user in ascending order and the records will follow its partition. The result in this case will be as follow:

```
    taskname  |skillname |user  |Partition
    --------------------------------------
    taskCCCC  |skill3333 |user1 |3
    taskBBBB  |skill1111 |user2 |2 
    taskAAAA  |skill1111 |user3 |1   
              |skill2222 |      |1
    taskDDDD  |skill1111 |user4 |4   
              |skill2222 |      |4
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: `order by "user" nulls last`?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: sorry, it shouldn't order by userid alone, but will follow its own partition. Let me modify my question.

Answer (score 0):

First option is using an [Order By](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) keyword and `NULLS LAST`

```
select * from table order by user NULLS LAST
```

If your SQL doesn't support `NULLS` you can use the value [IS NULL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp) expression

```
select * from table order by user IS NULL, user
```

If the user's field is null then the expression `IS NULL` returns 1 else 0. So the rows with not null value(0) will be first, and the rows with null value(1) will be last when a ascending sort. 
Next rows will be sorted by value of user's field.

Comment: Hi, how about the sorting of user follows its own partition, as modified question above?

Answer (score 0):

ANSI SQL supports `NULLS LAST`:

```
order by user nulls last
```

Not all databases support this construct.  It is easily replace by a two-key search:

```
order by (case when user is not null then 1 else 2 end),  -- "NULLS LAST"
         user
```